# Problem with running c++ opencv program in linux: functions not declared

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV and I'm using c++.
I installed opencv in my ubuntu using the libopencv-dev and python3-opencv packegs in ubuntu 20.04 from this tutorial: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/
but when I try to run a sample program using this command `g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 Example1.cpp -o Example1` I get this error:

```
Example1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

Example1.cpp:5:2: error: ‘IplImage’ was not declared in this scope

    5 |  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
      |  ^~~~~~~~

Example1.cpp:5:12: error: ‘img’ was not declared in this scope

    5 |  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
      |            ^~~

Example1.cpp:5:18: error: ‘cvLoadImage’ was not declared in this scope

    5 |  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~

Example1.cpp:6:29: error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZED’ was not declared in this scope

    6 |  cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZED );
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Example1.cpp:6:2: error: ‘cvNamedWindow’ was not declared in this scope

    6 |  cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZED );
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Example1.cpp:7:2: error: ‘cvShowImage’ was not declared in this scope

    7 |  cvShowImage( "Example1", img );
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~

Example1.cpp:8:2: error: ‘cvWaitKey’ was not declared in this scope

    8 |  cvWaitKey(0);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~

Example1.cpp:9:2: error: ‘cvReleaseImage’ was not declared in this scope

    9 |  cvReleaseImage( &img );
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Example1.cpp:10:2: error: ‘cvDestroyWindow’ was not declared in this scope

    10 |  cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
       |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

here is the source code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZED );
    cvShowImage( "Example1", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );

}
```

and the pkg-config output(if it's needed):

**p4n0@p4n0-desktop:~/Desktop/Example_Project$ pkg-config --cflags opencv**

-I/usr/local/include/opencv4

**p4n0@p4n0-desktop:~/Desktop/Example_Project$ pkg-config --libs opencv**

-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core

Comment: You are likely missing one or more required includes in your source code.

Comment: Include what you use. Link to what you use.

Comment: all this obsolete C stuff has been removed from OpenCV 4

Comment: Understanding how header files work, and when and how to include them, is something that's covered fairly early in a traditional C++ learning curriculum. I would think that by the time someone moves to using fairly advanced, dedicated, special-purpose libraries like OpenCV they would already have a pretty good grasp of these basics. Attempting to jump straight into advanced topics like OpenCV, before being fully up to speed on C++ fundamentals, usually ends in tears. You can't take any shortcuts when learning C++. Perhaps you should slow down a little bit and focus on the basics, first?

Comment: You are trying to compile C-api mode which is already deprecated

Answer (score 1):

To use [IplImage](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d5b/structIplImage.html), you need to include `opencv2/core/types_c.h`

Edit:- Since you are using OpenCV4, those includes are not available for you. They were removed.

In C++, like other languages to use a function you need to import it so the compiler can find the function during it's compilation step

Off topic suggestion:- This applies in case you are not forced to use IplImage etc.

If you are allowed to use Modern OpenCV, and are not restricted by old versions, prefer the Modern solutions not the C API.

[IplImage etc. were removed from OpenCV4.](https://opencv.org/opencv-4-0/)